# How to shuffle table rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me how to shuffle or randomize table row

I have table "478mill_scrub_final" contains 13980515 records with id and email field ,email filed contain record starting with a to z (alphabetic order) , I need to randomize table (shuffle) table , 
I have created new table 478mill_scrub_final_1

```
INSERT  INTO 478mill_scrub_final_1
SELECT *
FROM 478mill_scrub_final
ORDER BY RAND()
```

But above query do not respond

I need to do operation on same table

Please help

Comment: Do you have to do this in mysql? It would be alot easier if you did it with code...

Comment: Yes I have to do in mysql , Let me try with code and check how much time it will take

Comment: Why would you want to tamper with the order in which tuples are _stored_ in a table? Can't you `select .... order by xyz` at any given time?

Comment: There is no 'stored order' per se. So this operation is superfluous.

Comment: I need to give table unique data every day to client  , once one record given to client , It must not be repeated

Comment: If you want to give unique data.. why dont you select data based on row numbers.

Comment: Yes I am selecting based on row number but record (email field) must not be on alphabet order